# How to use multiple conditions using #if while forming a Table in ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I am forming a Table dynamically using Ember

How can i use nested if while forming the table

Something like this

```
{{#if ismorethanone && model.hasSize}}
                            <td> Hai  </td>
                            {{else}}
                                <td> Bye </td>
                        {{/if}}
```

My code

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Participant</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ParticipantList">
        {{#each person in model}}
            <tr>
                <td> {{person.name}}</td>
                <td> {{person.city}}</td>
                {{#if ismorethanone}}
                     <td><img src="image.jpg" alt="Remove" {{action "removeUser" person.name}}></td>
                {{/if}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
   </table>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/1937/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [`ember-truth-helpers`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers):

```
{{#if (and ismorethanone && model.hasSize)}}
  foo
{{else}}
  bar
{{/if}
```

or just nest the `if`s:

```
{{#if foo}}
  {{#if bar}}
    one
  {{else}}
    two
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: thanks for the code , but nested if are not working , tried as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/1944/

Comment: You *do* know that in this twiddle is `ember 1.2.0`? Thats quite old, the current version is `3.1`.

Comment: oh dear, I really recommend you to upgrade. And next time mention this in your question, **a lot has changed!**
However for your concrete twiddle, you've forgot the second `}` to close the second `{{#if}}`. I've had the same typo in my answer, will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#if (and ismorethanone model.hasSize)}}
  foo
{{else}}
  bar
{{/if}
```

will works, do not need "&&" between ismorethanone and model.hasSize